# MariaDB Load Data Infile - Can't read last line

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, load-data-infile

The last line of my CSV reads

```
58,5/3/17,8:30 PM,Jazz L6/7,0,,Thursday,1074,black,
```

The last comma is there because there is nothing in the last field. But there is NO carriage return after the last line.

But I get an error `"row 59 doesn't contain data for all columns"`

So if I go and change the last line to read:

```
58,5/3/18,8:30 PM,Jazz L6/7,0,,Thursday,1074,black,test
```

OR I have to put a carriage return... It will work.

Here is my PHP code that generates the query:

```
    $query = <<<eof
        TRUNCATE TABLE `eventstmp`;
        LOAD DATA INFILE '$target'
        INTO TABLE `eventstmp`
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        (EventCode,EventDate,GameTime,TeamName1,Versus, TeamName2, AgeGroup, Photographer, TextDescription, Location);
        delete from `eventstmp` limit 1;
        update `eventstmp` set `EventCode`=lpad(`EventCode`,3,'0');
        update `eventstmp` set `Import`=0 where exists(select 1 from `events` join `vwactiveevent` on '$MainEventID'=`events`.`MainEventID` where `events`.`Eve
ntCode`=`eventstmp`.`EventCode`);
eof;
```

I have tried this on two different databases that should be the same.  It looks like the description of the eventstmp table on each database is the same.  The SQL mode of each database is also the same.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've tried changing the `'LINES TERMINATED BY' from \n to \r\n.`  I've also tried escaping the \  so it would be: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'`

Not sure what else to try

Comment: So fix how the file is generated

Comment: Too much human factor involvement on the file generation. Would be safer fix it programmatically.

Comment: I doubt it. If human factor is the issue, then the human will always find a way to mess the file up in a new and interesting way that you had not thought of in your Fix It Here code

Comment: Well since we can't teach the human...  and we can't program the computer.... Guess we should all go home.

Comment: Well then you will have to preprocess the file and look for the last char. If its a comma add a newline or whatever fixes it. Of course having to do that you may as well update the database from a PHP script that reads the file and processes it line by line.... Looking for the idiot situation on the last line or maybe other lines as well

Comment: What about using ESCAPED BY ' " ' right after your OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY clause?

Comment: MySQL is going to want clean data, so if the data is dirty you need to clean it prior to delivering it to MySQL. You can do this in PHP if you want.